# How to change the thresholds for failure and warning on SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK Pipeline?

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk, s4hana

We are using SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK pipeline in our project and have below configuration in place for JMeter tests. However I would like to change the thresholds for failure and warning. How can I customize these values?

```
checkJMeter:
   options: ''
   testPlan: './performance-tests/JMeter/*' 
   dockerImage: 'famiko/jmeter-base'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below configuration for customizing thresholds.

```
checkJMeter:
 options: ''
 testPlan: './performance-tests/JMeter/*' 
 dockerImage: 'famiko/jmeter-base'
 failThreshold : 80     # configurable
 unstableThreshold: 70  # Should always be less than failThreshold
```

Default values for error and warning are 100 and 90 respectively.